# How to plot data using oriented coloring in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I got DTI color FA data which is [120, 120, 80, 3], the last 3 value should stand for rgb value, I'm wondering how can I use matplotlib to plot a slice with the color information inside(oriented coloring). For example slice [:,:,40]? There is an example of the kind of effect I want to achieve
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just treat it as an common image will work! `nimage=data[:,:,middle,:]; plt.imshow(nimage.transpose(1,0,2))`